# "be in love" vs. "fall in love" in a perfect construction

Tags: meaning, tense, grammaticality, present-perfect, perfect-constructions

Which one is correct grammatically?

> 1. I've **been** in love with you ever since I saw you
> 2. I've **fallen** in love with you ever since I saw you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tense and aspect in 'since' clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76546/tense-and-aspect-in-since-clause)

Comment: The bit that you may be missing is that "be in love" refers to a state, and so continue over a period; "fall in love" refers to a transition, which is momentary.

Comment: As per @Colin Fine, because "fall in in love" is a momentary event, 2 doesn't make sense as the falling is an event, not a state, and the event is not ongoing (even though the resulting state has been).

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is grammatically correct:

> I've been in love with you ever since I saw you.

The second sentence needs to be rephrased, for example

> I fell in love with you at the moment I first saw you.

Comment: or perhaps more likely, ***...when** I first saw you*. But ***...at first sight*** is probably the idiomatic standard.